# I'm getting an exception in cloud firestore transactions

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting a cloud firestore exception which says "Error performing transaction, Every document read in a transaction must also be written., null". This problem only occurs when I'm trying to run transaction by creating a document of user by his e-mail, everything works fine when it's on UID.

```
Future<bool> updateFavorites(String email, String recipeId) {
  DocumentReference favoritesReference =
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(email);
  return Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(favoritesReference);
if (postSnapshot.exists) {
  if (!postSnapshot.data['favorites'].contains(recipeId)) {
    await tx.update(favoritesReference, <String, dynamic>{
      'favorites': FieldValue.arrayUnion([recipeId])
    });
  } else {
    await tx.update(favoritesReference, <String, dynamic>{
      'favorites': FieldValue.arrayRemove([recipeId])
    });
  }
} else {
  await tx.set(favoritesReference, {
    'favorites': [recipeId]
  });
}
  }).then((result) {
return true;
  }).catchError((error) {
print('Error: $error');
return false;
  });
}
```

This is the function where the transaction takes place and this function is called here:

```
  void handleFavoritesListChanged(String recipeID) {
    updateFavorites(appState.user.email, recipeID) //the user hold the current firebase user
.then((result) {
      if (result == true) {
        setState(() {
        if (!StateModel.favorites.contains(recipeID))
             StateModel.favorites.add(recipeID);
          else
            StateModel.favorites.remove(recipeID); //StateModel is a class which has the empty list of favorites
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

the above code works great when I use user.uid instead of use.email. 
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it should be the `string` email ('email') pointing to the path in the below (edited) and not the email object itself.

```
DocumentReference favoritesReference =
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('email')
```

Comment: But this thing works with another function known as placeOrder() which has same code but does not check if favorites contains recipe Id or not

Comment: So I want to be sure that in your firestore db, you have a collection called 'users' and a document following the collection named 'email'. It would odd to set it this way, but that's how the code read above. What you likely have is a users collection, with a document for each user which has a map to certain key:value pairs for each user. So for the above, it would be: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('jonny123')... to get access to the map that includes user Jonny's email, username, etc.

Comment: I found that the main problem is not with email but it's with the, method contains(), if(!postSnapshot.data['favorites'].contains(recipeId)), there is another function which is similar to the code I've shown in the question, the another function I have works on email and doesn't have this line (if(!postSnapshot.data['favorites'].contains(recipeId)),) so this is where the problem is, the method contains was called on null